# How to structure pages with BottomNavigationBar in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm not sure how I should structure my pages when using a BottomNavBar.
Right now, I use a `MainScreen` which contains a `Scaffold` and `BottomNavBar`

The `MainScreen` widget contains a list with the different pages. Is this the recommended way to use the bottomNavBar? I know I could also use the Navigator to navigate between the screens, but then it launches a different window for each page, which isn't what you expect when using a bottomNavBar. The way I implemented it now works fine, but how could I use a `FloatingActionButton` in the one of the screens? Do you always need a Scaffold for that?

```
  List<Widget> screens = [
    Screen1(),
    Screen2(),
    Screen3()
  ];

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(Constants.APP_NAME),
      ),
      body: screens[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNav(onBottomNavPressed: onBottomNavPressed,),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You want to show fab inside one of the screens, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official `BottomNavigationBar` class [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html), providing widgets as a `<Widget>[ ]`is the recommended way to provide widgets. And for the second part of your question, yes. a `FloatingActionButton` can only be included inside a `Scaffold`, so you should add one in the widget where you need to use the `FloatingActionButton`.

Comment: So in one of the screens where in want the FAB, I should return a new Scaffold with a FAB?

Comment: Yes, that what you should do.

Comment: But then I just get a Scaffold inside a Scaffold.

Comment: yes, but it's the only way to get what you need. This github issue was discussing your same problem, and they were arguing it is normal. Even flutter contributors modified `Scaffold` to make nesting easier https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7036

Comment: @DreamsInHD It's not only way actually, there is a another solution without transiting between scaffolds, with just one scaffold with multiple bodies.

Comment: Okay, what is the other solution?